# ASUS software atkexComSvc.exe keeps the clock at 100%

Tags: motherboard, clock, resources

I bought an ASUS motherboard 970 Gaming Pro Aura, all runs ok except that a service from its software (atkexComSvc.exe) keeps the clock at 100% and uses about 17% to 25% of the processor resources.

I read on the Internet that there's no fix for this, so I'm here to get some recommendations.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to uninstall the unnecessary software

Comment: I tried, but this file is in related to all the ASUS software and some software is useful, like AiSuite III, Audio Driver, Ligthing_control, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One possible resolution, as noted in [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pcmasterrace/comments/4udho3/fix_for_ai_suite_iiiatkexcomsvcexe_using_a_lot_of/), is to open up the AI Suite III program, select "Mobo Connect" from the menu at the left, and re-select "disabled" for the "Device" option under both "Keyboard/Mouse sharing" and "Audio Mode," even if the curernt setting is "Please select device."

After pressing apply, the settings revert to "please select device"; but this does appear to cause `atkexComSvc.exe` to calm down.